# tell LAN DNS Server what the computer name is

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, dns

Suppose you have a freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 computer in your companies LAN with the name `new-box`, which you could set while installing Ubuntu. You want to allow other users to resolve your IP adress from your computers name, e.g.

```
#coworker can do:
$ ssh coworker@new-box
#instead of:
$ ssh coworker@192.168.2.123
```

How to configure your system to tell the DNS server your computer's name?

Comment: install dnsmasq as a dns+dhcp server on your network, it can automatically pick up names that are defined locally.  It exists as an installable package for ubuntu, all config info can be found on their website.  don't forget to disable your existing dhcp server though, because forgetting to do so could cause some very strange problems on your network.

Comment: You can instruct dhclient on Linux to make DNS updates, but most (sane) DNS servers will reject these. The usual way to make an update based on DHCP leases is to make the DHCP *server* send a signed request on your behalf.

Comment: @Flexo I like this very much. Sounds quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an entry in `/etc/hosts` on the machine that will be referencing the machine by your intended name. This file contains a list of overrided DNS lookups

The entry you need to add is the following

```
192.168.2.123 new-box
```

Now whenever the DNS is asked to resolve `new-box` the ip address you want is specified.

EDIT:

For a more scalable DNS approach you should use something like [Dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq)

This will allow you to send dns requests from your computers to this LAN DNS server which will return the hostnames on the local network.

1. You will need to setup the server. It is best to read online documentation as your implimentation will be very custom.
2. On the router that is serving all of this computers you will need to modify DCHP set the primary name server to the IP address of the computer that will be running Dnsmasq.
3. Start using your local hostnames

Comment: there is already a line `127.0.1.1 new-box`, does that conflict with the line I should add now?

Comment: @erikb note that you'll need to put this on your coworker's PC if you do it that way - /etc/hosts isn't really "DNS", it's local to each machine

Comment: @secretformula - sounds more like they're editing the file on the wrong machine

Comment: If you are looking for a more global solution you will need to set up a small DNS server

Comment: @Flexo you seem to be right. Make sure that you are editing the hosts file on the machine that you are accessing the system from.

Comment: @secretformula not downvoting you but editing `/etc/hosts` on all machines doesn't scale at all.

Comment: I'll really need a global solution, though. As I said, it's a company network and I'm not an admin. I can't go to all computers and rewrite their configs. (Even if I am I probably wouldn't want to)

Comment: You can also set up SMB this should work for LAN on Windows at least.